# If the Sets $A=\{x|x>4\ or\ x<0\}$, $B=\{x | ax-1>0\}$, and $A\cup B=A$, find the values of $a$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

### Question:

If the Sets $A=\{x|x>4\ or\ x<0\}$, $B=\{x | ax-1>0\}$, and $A\cup B=A$, find the values of $a$.

### My Working:

If $A\cup B=A$, then we have $B \subset A$.

If $B = \varnothing$, $ax-1\le0$, and I cannot find $a$ from this.

If $B \neq \varnothing$, I cannot find $a$ either.

Could anyone please help?

Comment: $B$ contains the set $x>1/a$., say $a>0$, What is the value(s) of a so that this set is in A?

Comment: If $a >0$, then for every $x \in B$, $x> 1/a$. Then, $a \geq 1/4$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $a>0$. Then $B=\{ x|x>1/a \},$ which is a subset of $A$ for $1/a\geq 4\iff a\leq 1/4.$

Suppose $a<0$. Then  $B=\{x|x<1/a \}\subseteq A.$

Suppose $a=0$. Then $B=\emptyset\subseteq A.$

So $a\leq 1/4.$